# stop cold air around window cracks

Tags: windows, leak, interior, winterizing

Around my living room window i see little crack (pic attached) from where cold air seems to enter. There are no cracks on the exterior of the house.
Can anyone suggest what is the best product i can use to cover these cracks.[image]
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6):

It looks like the caulk there is old and cracked. Scrape it all out so you have a good surface to work with and use a premium acrylic caulk. DAP extreme stretch or 230 would be good choices if you dont want to work with silicone. If the gaps are larger than 1/4" you should use window expanding foam or backer rod first to fill the gap before caulking. Then use a wet sponge and your finger or caulk tool to smooth out the bead

Answer (score 5):

Looks like caulk was applied once before and has cracked due to movement. You'll want to scrape that all away and apply new caulk. Silicone would work, but it's not paintable, so consider that.

Comment: There are paintable silicone caulks.

Comment: There are caulks _with_ silicone that are paintable. There are no paintable silicone caulks.